# IBM Connections Cloud custom contextual data

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-connections

I followed the [official documentation](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Dev+Guide+topics#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_Communities_apps_with_the_URL_Widget&content=sdkcontent) and created a minor community app for my website.

What I'd like to know is if there's a way "to shim" custom data to IBM Connections Cloud when uploading my app as a JSON and then retrieve it inside the `message` handler after my app loads:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {

  if (event.origin === "https://apps.collabservnext.com"){
    // event.data contains the full context
    console.log("Running in community named " + event.data.source.resourceId);
  }
}, false);

parent.postMessage("appReady", "*");
```

So far I'm only getting the `extraContent`, `source` and `user` JSON keys in `event.data`. It would be awesome if there was a way to retrieve say `hello: world`.

Thanks.